# difference between tsql, access sql and pl/sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql

i am very confused

please help to clarify these differences!

are they all completely different languages? what is the overlap?

Comment: The 'overlap' is standard SQL which they all support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSQL - Transact SQL
PL/SQL - Is SQL for Oracle SQL Server
Access SQL - Is a hacked version of SQL

TSQL and PL/SQL are both based off of SQL ISO/ANSI Standards.  It depends on the version of SQL Server(TSQL) or Oracle(PL/SQL) for what ISO/ANSI version they are using.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL for more info.

TSQL and PL/SQL just have extra functionality beyond ISO/ANSI SQL put in by the companies that made them.  In general the ISO/ANSI SQL standard deal specifically with how you can Query a database and what structures you can have in the database (e.g. tables, triggers, stored procs, etc).  TSQL and PL/SQL are true programming languages in that they can do loops and other things that a programming languages can do.  Simply put TSQL and PL/SQL are turing complete and the ISO standards are not.

I am not sure about Access.  I think it is just a hacked up version of SQL.

Comment: One big thing about SQL in MS Access is that it supports VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

Answer (score 6):

T-SQL and PL/SQL are extensions of SQL.  Overlap is entirely dependent upon which versions of Oracle and SQL Server you are comparing.  IE:

WITH syntax: Has been supported by Oracle since 9i - SQL Server support started with 2005.

ANSI-92 support: Oracle 9i+ vs SQL Server 2005+

- Analytics (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK)
- CASE statement

Regex Support: Oracle 10g+ vs SQL Server 2005+ (requiring CLR enabling & CLR function created)

PIVOT/UNPIVOT: SQL Server 2005+ vs Oracle 11g+

COALESCE: Oracle 9i+ vs SQL Server 2000+

Answer (score 2):

There are [SQL standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization), that most RDBMSs follow, but in order to be competitive, most companies add their own extensions.

Many times these are extensions that are simply not in a standard.